# Angularjs route resolve not populating model before loading controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to populate my model from backend(with label and messages) before my contoller get loads. My method is working fine it connects with backend and gets the data but when I am viewing that variable in controller it is coming as undefined. My variable is "Model"

This is my route file

```
mainApp
    .config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
        .when(AngularRoutesFactory.AIMSAdmin.SearchBookings, {
              templateUrl: aimsAdminViewBase + "Bookings/SearchBookings.html",
              controller: "SearchPerioperativeBookingController",
              resolve: {
                  "Model": function (BookingFactory) {
                      return BookingFactory.GetSearchModel();
                  }
              },
              requireAIMSAuthorizeUser: true
          })
          .otherwise({
              redirectTo: AngularRoutesFactory.MainApp.BaseUrl
          });
    }]);
```

My Factory is

```
mainApp.factory("BookingFactory", ["$location", "MainFactory",
function ($location, MainFactory) {
 bookingsFactory.GetSearchModel = function () {
        bookingsFactory.MainFactory.QueryAPI(apiEndpoint + "GetSearchModel", "GET", function (response) {
            bookingsFactory.SearchBookingCriteria = response;
            return bookingsFactory.SearchBookingCriteria;
        }, null, null, bookingsFactory.LangInfo.Message_GettingBookingModel);
    }
 return bookingsFactory;


}]);
```

And this is my controller

```
mainApp.controller("SearchBookingController", ["$scope", "BookingFactory", "$rootScope", "$location"
, function ($scope, BookingFactory, $rootScope, $location, Model) {
    $scope.bbb = Model;

}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took guidance from @Fedaykin and came up with following working solution. Please let me know if it is wrong

I just changed my factory method and resolve function by applying $q.defer method and got it working

Changed my factory GetSearchModel method with following code

```
bookingsFactory.GetSearchModel = function () {
        bookingsFactory.MainFactory.QueryAPI(apiEndpoint + "GetSearchModel", "GET", function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }, null, null, bookingsFactory.LangInfo.Message_GettingBookingModel);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

What I did in route file

```
var bookingModel= function ($q, BookingFactory) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    BookingFactory.GetSearchModel().then(
              function (data) {
                  deferred.resolve(data);
              }, function () {
                  deferred.reject();
              }
          );
    return deferred.promise;
};
bookingModel.$inject = ["$q", "BookingFactory"];
```

Then in resolve all I did

```
 .when(AngularRoutesFactory.AIMSAdmin.SearchBookings, {
              templateUrl: aimsAdminViewBase + "Bookings/SearchBookings.html",
              controller: "SearchBookingController",
              resolve: {
                  "Model": bookingModel
              },
              requireAIMSAuthorizeUser: true
          })
```

And in controller voila I got the value

```
mainApp.controller("SearchBookingController", ["$scope", "InitializeMainFactory", "$rootScope", "$location", "Model"
, function ($scope, InitializeMainFactory, $rootScope, $location, Model) {

    $scope.Model = Model;

}]);
```

Comment: thats it! the only difference between this and the one I posted is that you put the function into the bookingModel variable, if you paste that in the resolve part you'll get the same result :D

Comment: you are absolutely right. I just did that to support minification and I think angular guys says that It is good a practice.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Try handling it this way:

```
mainApp.config(["$routeProvider", "$q", function ($routeProvider, $q) {
    .when(AngularRoutesFactory.AIMSAdmin.SearchBookings, {
          templateUrl: aimsAdminViewBase + "Bookings/SearchBookings.html",
          controller: "SearchPerioperativeBookingController",
          resolve: {
              Model: function (BookingFactory, $q) {

                  var deferred = $q.defer();
                  BookingFactory.GetSearchModel().then(
                            function (data) {
                                deferred.resolve(data);
                            }, function () {
                                deferred.reject();
                            }
                        );
                  return deferred.promise;
              }
          },
          requireAIMSAuthorizeUser: true
      })
      .otherwise({
          redirectTo: AngularRoutesFactory.MainApp.BaseUrl
      });
}]);
```

Comment: It is still undefined..:(

Comment: Hmm, what about BookingFactory.GetSearchModel(); is it a promise?

Comment: yes it is cause I am passing my function to main factory which executes that function in then which i think returns promise

Comment: @AtulChaudhary You need to make sure that you return that promise from the `resolve`. Since you call several functions in the resolve, each of those functions needs to return the promise up to and including the function that is used in the resolve.

Comment: Does that mean I have to use $q method?

Comment: I think you cannot inject $q in config. Please correct me if I am wrong but your answer gave me the idea and I am about to post the working solution here for future reference ...Thanks @Fedaykin

Comment: Nice to be helpful, concerning $q, I actually have some code that does it, but now that I'm looking it up I see it is using angular 1.1.5, so I don't know if it's working or not. In any case, you should be able to use $q.

Comment: I just posted the working solution please let me know what u think Thanks once again from Australia